# Updating MySQL Record with PHP - SQL works, php side does not

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I've been testing my sql in phpmyadmin, I know the sql works fine but when I call it through a form button It doesn't do anything. Can anyone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong.

This is the php in the main form page:

```
<?php
    echo 
    "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
<th>health</th>
<th>damage</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $cell) {

        echo "\n<td>$cell</td>";
    }

    echo '<td><form method="POST" action="attack.php">
    <input name="update" type="button" value="Update Record" />
    <input type="hidden" name="'.$row[1].'" /></form></td></tr>';
    echo "\n\n";
    echo "test";

 }
?>

<?php
require_once('config.php');

$sqltest = $sqltest - 5;
    $id = floor($_GET['id']);

if($id > 0)
{
$sql1="UPDATE ajax_demo SET Health = Health - Damage";
$result=mysql_query($sql1);
mysql_close();
}
?>
```

obvisouly I would add varibles nito the sql string but for testing purposes I left it as such. If anyone can help it would be muchly appricated.

Comment: $sql1="UPDATE ajax_demo SET Health = 'Health - Damage'";
Change this .

Comment: 1) You are not escaping values when injecting them in HTML. 2) You don't check whether `mysql_query()` is successful. 3) You are using a deprecated extension.

Comment: Álvaro G. Vicario Can extend on those points please?

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
$sql1="UPDATE ajax_demo SET `Health` = `Health` - `Damage`"; // it will set the actual computed value.
```

if you use

```
`Health` = 'Health - Damage' // it will set text Health - Damage not the computed value
```

Comment: Ah thanks alot, That has been changed. What other reasons would be for this not to work now?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replys, are you calling it through a form like I am? So on BTN click for action = attack.php ?

Comment: No, I have checked this query in phpmyadmin, but it will sure work in php code. :)

Comment: Ah thanks, Well I tested the code out in the main page, Worked fine, But It wont work when I call it from the echo'd forms so the code sits in attack.php when the btn is pressed it calls that attack.php file which does nothing. Any Idea why that would be ?

Comment: oh my problem I believe now would be php is server side only? so I have to use ajax or somthing similar?

Comment: @user1284386 yes `php` is server side. :)

Comment: Could you point me in the direction on how to call .php through forms with ajax? the sources Ive checked seem to do things alot differently then how im trying to do it!